# QT TabBar side pane only

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, tabwidget

I have added a QTabWidget which is checkable. I want to hide all tabs (panes only) when the TabBar is unchecked and vice versa. Is there any way to make only pane invisible and tab bar will not disappear?
I add the image reference related to what I want in output:

Initially both tab pane is minimize and when i click on the tab it will maximize:

[image]

after clicking pane is maximize and again i click it will minimize and vice versa:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using QTabWidget. You can use a [QTabBar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabbar.html#details) and implement the functionality you desire hiding the corresponding widget.

here is some sample code of a new widget application example within qt creator

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"

#include <QTabBar>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    m_tabbar = new QTabBar(this->centralWidget());
    m_tabbar->addTab("Hello");
    m_tabbar->addTab("World");
    m_tabbar->setShape(QTabBar::RoundedWest);
    m_tabbar->setGeometry(0,0,this->height(), 200);


    connect(m_tabbar, SIGNAL(tabBarClicked(int)), this, SLOT(changedTab(int)));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void
MainWindow::changedTab(int idx)
{
    m_tabbar->setCurrentIndex(idx);
    ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(idx);
}
```